# Handling keyboard input in win32, WM_CHAR or WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP?

Tags: c++, winapi

So in the text editor program that i've been working on, I've used WM_CHAR to process input from the keyboard. However, I found that some of the character mesages are not recorded. For example, if I use [shift]+ number key to type a symbol such as % or &, some re recorded while others such as [shift]+9 (which results in ')'), are not recorded. So, I'm wondering if I should use WM_KEYDOWN/WMKEYUP pair to handle keyboard input. I once wrote a keylogger in assembly(actually it was just a tutorial that i was trying out) and had used WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP pairs and that worked out quite good. So, should I move on to this, or is it something unusual that is happening with my program?

Thanks,

Devjeet

Comment: I believe the WM_CHAR messages are generated automatically by the default window procedure for WM_KEYDOWN.

Comment: Depending on whether this is just for personal use or not, you may also want to support IME's so that users can enter languages such as Japanese, Chinese, Korean. Rather than reinventing the wheel from scrach, it might be worth taking a look at the open-source code editing component scintilla.org and seeing if it meets your needs, or seeing how it handles these issues. Note that even scintilla doesn't handle issues like bi-directional text, such as Hebrew/Arabic. Handling Unicode properly has some fun issues too, since a displayable character on screen may map to one or more WCHARs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I resolved this error. Apparently, windows works in really strange ways. I had put in certain conditions to handle the arrow keys. I used SPY++ and then analysed everything. Then I narrowed down to those conditions(in a switch statement) and then commented them out. It works. It seems that when you press [shift]+9, windows sends a VK_LEFT in the wParam of message WM_CHAR.

Comment: @devjeetroy - you shouldn't be checking for VK_ values in WM_CHAR - see my long-winded answer below for more info...

Comment: @MarkRansom:  I believe WM_CHAR is generated by the TranslateMessage in the message loop, not by DefWindowProc.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy - correct - from ms doc - `WM_CHAR  - Posted to the window with the keyboard focus when a WM_KEYDOWN message is translated by the TranslateMessage function. The WM_CHAR message contains the character code of the key that was pressed.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This is really a long reply to your comment above, but putting it in an answer because it's too long for a comment :)

The core issue to understand here is that keys and characters are not quite the same thing. Some (but not all) keys generate characters; some keys generate different characters depending on shift or other keyboard state. And to implement an editor, you need to handle both textual input and also non-textual keyboard input like arrow keys. Now the long-winded version, picking off from what seems to be an incorrect assumption:

> Apparently, windows works in really strange ways. [...] It seems that when you press [shift]+9, windows sends a VK_LEFT in the wParam of message WM_CHAR

Sounds like you might be mixing two things up here. The thing with WM_CHAR is that it gives you character codes for textual characters: so if someone presses the 9 key, you'll get '9'. If someone presses SHIFT+9, Windows will take the shift state into account - and you get '(' (if using US keyboard). But you won't ever get a WM_CHAR for arrow keys, HOME, END, and so on, since they are not textual characters. WM_KEYDOWN, on the other hand, does not deal in characters, but in VK_ codes; so pressing 9 gives you VK_9 regardless of shift state; and left arrow gives you VK_LEFT - again regardles of shift state.

The things is that WM_CHAR and WM_KEYDOWN both give you two parts to the overall input picture - but you really have to handle both to get the full picture. And have to be aware that the wParam is a very different thing in both cases. It's a character code for WM_CHAR, but a VK_ code for WM_KEYDOWN. Don't mix the two.

And to make things more confusing, *VK_ values share the same values as valid characters*. Open up WinUser.h (it's in the include dir under the compiler installation dir), and look for VK_LEFT:

```
#define VK_LEFT           0x25
```

Turns out that 0x25 is also the code for the '%' character (see any ascii/unicode table for details). So if WM_CHAR gets 0x25, it means shift-5 was pressed (assuming US keyboard) to create a '%'; but if WM_KEYDOWN gets 0x25, it means left arrow (VK_LEFT) was pressed. And to add a bit more confusion, the Virtual Key codes for the A-Z keys and 0-9 keys happen to be the same as the 'A'-'Z' and '0'-'9' characters - which makes it seem like chars and VK_'s are interchangable. But they're not: the code for lower case 'a', 0x61, is VK_NUMPAD1! (So getting 0x61 in WM_CHAR does mean 'a', getting it in WM_KEYDOWN means NUMPAD1. And if a user does hit the 'A' key in unshifted state, what you actually get is first a VK_A (same value as 'A') in WM_KEYDOWN, which gets translated to WM_CHAR of 'a'.)

So tying all this together, the typical way to handle keyboard is to use all of the following:

- Use WM_CHAR to handle textual input: actual text keys. wParam is the character that you want to append to your string, or do whatever else with. This does all the shift- processing for you.
- Use WM_KEYDOWN to handle 'meta' keys - like arrow keys, home, end, page up, and so on. Pass all the A-Z/0-9 values through, the default handling will turn them into WM_CHARs that you can handle in your WM_CHAR handler. (You can also handle numpad keys here if you want to use them for special functionality; otherwise they 'fall through' to end up as numeric WM_CHARs, depending on numlock state. Windows takes care of this, just as it handles shift state for the alphabetic keys.)
- If you want to handle ALT- combos explicitly (rather than using an accelerator table), you'll get those via WM_SYSKEYDOWN.

I think there are some keys that might show up in both - Enter might show up as both a WM_KEYDOWN of VK_RETURN and as either \r or \n WM_CHAR - but my preference would be to handle it in WM_KEYDOWN, to keep editing key handling separate from text keys.

Comment: Thanks man! that explained everything. I was kinda confused as to why VK_LEFT was the same as a ). Now your answer makes everything clear. Thanks a lot man! very elaborate answer!

Comment: This is still a great answer, but nowadays I would suggest using WM_UNICHAR before WM_CHAR.

Comment: You should add to your answer that WM_CHAR is not really sent by the OS, instead is generated by TranslateMessage() from WM_KEYDOWN events - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char

Comment: Adding to @AdrianMcCarthy comment - Both WM_CHAR, and WM_UNICODE are Unicode, with former being UTF-16, while latter UTF-32. from ms docs - `The WM_UNICHAR message is similar to WM_CHAR, but it uses Unicode Transformation Format (UTF)-32, whereas WM_CHAR uses UTF-16.` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-unichar

Answer (score 5):

[Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460760.aspx) will show you the messages being sent to a window, so you can experiment and see what messages are appropriate for your application.

If you have Visual Studio installed, it should be in your Start menu, under Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio -> Visual Studio Tools -> Spy++.

- [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The helpful message above inspired me to create this snippet, which gives you a human-readable indication of what key was pressed from any WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP/WM_SYSKEYDOWN/WM_SYSKEYUP independent of the state of the modifier keys.

```
// get the keyboard state
BYTE keyState[256];
GetKeyboardState(keyState);
// clear all of the modifier keys so ToUnicode will ignore them
keyState[VK_CONTROL] = keyState[VK_SHIFT] = keyState[VK_MENU] = 0;
keyState[VK_LCONTROL] = keyState[VK_LSHIFT] = keyState[VK_LMENU] = 0;
keyState[VK_RCONTROL] = keyState[VK_RSHIFT] = keyState[VK_RMENU] = 0;
// convert the WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP/WM_SYSKEYDOWN/WM_SYSKEYUP to characters
UINT scanCode = (inLParam >> 16) & 0xFF;
int i = ToUnicode(inWParam, scanCode, keyState, outBuf, inOutBufLenCharacters, 0);
outBuf[i] = 0;
```

By modifying the keyState array so that all the modifier keys are clear, ToUnicode will always output the unshifted key you pressed. (So, on the English keyboard you'll never get '%' but always '5') as long as it's a human readable key. You still have to do the VK_XXX checking to sense the arrow and other non-human readable keys however.

(I was trying to rig up a user editable "hot key" system in my app, and the distinction between WM_KEYXXX and WM_CHAR was making me nuts. The code above solved that problem.)

Comment: What's good about this is that you can use `ToUnicode` to test whether (and what!) the `WM_CHAR` message would be for a given `WM_KEYDOWN`, so you can ignore the `WM_CHAR` messages and handle everything in the `DOWN/UP` handlers.  Be sure to read the docs for `ToUnicode` to understand the return code!