# How to get scancode of key pressed?

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard

I need scancode (NOT ASCII value) of keys of keyboard when pressed in c++?
i have used:

```
getch();
```

but this only provides ascii values.

Comment: `C++` does not have the concept of "scancodes". You need to use a platform specific system function. On which platform are you running your application?

Comment: thanks for your reply..on windows platform

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, it depends on whether you are writing a console application or a GUI:

- [ReadConsoleInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is used for console
- you would handle a [`WM_CHAR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161741/handling-keyboard-input-in-win32-wm-char-or-wm-keydown-wm-keyup) event for a GUI.

From the context, it sounds as if you want the console api.  That reads an [`INPUT_RECORD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), within which (depending on the type of input) you would have a [KEY_EVENT_RECORD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The `wVirtualScanCode` in *that* is what you are looking for.

For further reading:

- [ReadConsoleInput: virtual and control keys](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?468159-ReadConsoleInput-virtual-and-control-keys)